# Undesirable highlighting of a keyword name (dh) occuring within an identifier (0dh)

Tags: listings, highlighting

I'm using the `x86masm` dialect of `Assembler` and register names are emphasized even when they occur inside of a label or a hexadecimal number. For example, `dh` is register, but `0dh` is a number, yet the `dh` part of it is emphasized. I haven't had this problem in `listings` with any other languages, so I'm assuming it's a problem with the language definition. Is there simple way to redefine the language so that this doesn't happen?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{courier, listings}

\lstset{
  language={[x86masm]Assembler},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  frame=single
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
cmp al, 0dh ; dh = register, 0dh = number
je somewhere
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `deletekeywords=...`. However, you should use another monotypefont like beramono.
Courier is not a good looking mono font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{courier, listings}

\lstset{
  language={[x86masm]Assembler},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  frame=single,
  deletekeywords={dh}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
cmp al, 0dh ; dh = register, 0dh = number
je somewhere
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I might still use the dh register somewhere else, and I'd want it emphasized there. Also, this happens with a lot of other registers (bh, ah, ch), and labels are even more likely to have mnemonics in them, so I might as well remove all highlighting if I'm gonna do it this way.

Comment: @Adrian: Where is the problem? Then change it only locally! `\begin{lstlisting}[deletekeywords={dh}]`

Comment: @Herbert: I think the problem is that the OP wants the register `dh` highlighted, but does not want it highlighted in the number `0dh`.  Seems that to get a complete general solution, the package would be required to parse the actual language to do that as opposed to just match keywords.

Comment: I did some more tests, and this is a listings problem, not just a problem with the language definition. It only happens with literals starting with digits, ending in a keyword, and containing no other letters. This problem is much more likely to occur in assembly than in other languages because of the short mnemonic names and ubiquity of hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Okay, I was able to solve this by turning on case sensitivity and making all hexadecimal digits uppercase.

Comment: @Adrian: Your last two comments might be worth to be given as an answer: They give some more hints about the root of the problem and provide a reasonable workaround. (Note that it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions, other members might profit from your solution!)

Comment: @Adrian I'm experiencing a similiar problem with ABAP where there are a lot of keywords. Your solution with case sensitivty seems to be a good workaround. It would have been nice to have had this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `listings` treats sequences of digits (and other characters) and sequences of letters separately. More specifically here, `listings` recognises the digit `0` and prints it out, and then recognises the keyword `dh` (defined by the `x86masm` language) and highlights it as such.

As Herbert wrote in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28433/21891), you can of course delete `dh` from the list of keywords, like so

```
deletekeywords={dh}
```

However, that approach is less than ideal, because it completely prevents any instance of identifier `dh` from being highlighted, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

A preferable approach is to tell `listings` to treat digits and letters together, not separately, by making digits "letters":

```
alsoletter=0123456789,
```

Then, `listings` will treat `0dh` as a single entity; `dh` will get highlighted, but `0dh` won't, as desired.

[image]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{courier, listings}

\lstset{
  language={[x86masm]Assembler},
% deletekeywords={dh},    % less than ideal
  alsoletter=0123456789,  % better 
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  frame=single,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
cmp al, 0dh ; dh = register, 0dh = number
je somewhere
--- TestTestTest: dh ---
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```